# Installing rvm on cygwin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation, cygwin, rvm

I'm trying to install Ruby Version Manager on cygwin. First it seems seems to pass, but both installations of ruby-1-9-2 and ruby-1-8-7 are failling.
All the way an annoying error line is repeating, even when I write such basic programs like `rvm help`I get this:

> .rvm/scripts/functions/logging: line 8: tput: command not found

or something similar

> .rvm/scripts/functions/logging: line 11: tput: command not found

I can provide full logs if needed.
Will be grateful for help and replies.

Comment: Would you be so kind to [go here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/942899/leon21#questions) and accept some answers that other people gave you before?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error says, you're missing `tput`. Run the cygwin setup, look for the `ncurses` package, and install it.